# If we delete a element from a string arraylist records should not get shifted

Tags: java, arraylist

I am working on project in which i am using string arraylist. In that i am supposed to delete a element from an arraylist but that element should become null, and arraylist should not get shifted after removing the element.
for ex..

```
List<String> lister= new ArrayList<String>();
lister.add("abc");
lister.add("def");
lister.add("tur");
```

now if i want to remove second element from list i wil use lister.remove(1). But i want that position should become null after deleting and elements should not get shifetd one step back, because i need to add an element on that position again.

Comment: Ummmmmmm. Set it to null? `lister.set(1,null)`?

Answer (score 8):

Don't remove it. Set it to `null`.

```
lister.set(1, null);
```

Comment: now if i want to add element again on that position (which is 1 in this case) then how should i do that? because i am getting error..OutOfMemory

Comment: @Hitman - Setting a new element follows the same pattern; for example: `lister.set(1, "xyz");`. This replaces the current element at position 1 with the new one (either `null` in my answer or `"xyz"` in the example here). If you're getting an `OutOfMemory` error, something is wrong somewhere else. You definitely won't get that error from simple `List` operations unless memory is already mostly consumed.

Comment: no dude everything is ok..but when i add elemement to that position i get an error..do u knw any other method to add element to list??

Comment: @Hitman - There's no way that will cause an OOM error. Please edit your question and post the actual code you are using that generates the error. Also, a stack trace would be most helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you want to use a String[] instead, then.  Or don't use `remove`, instead just set the index you want to make go away to a null value.